# Loss of quantum coherence due to gravity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, gravity, quantum-information, standard-model

Consider a particle which moving inside a gravitational field.Will it lose its quantum coherence?

According to GR , the particle will follow a geodesic but if it does then shouldn't its wavefunction have been collapsed?

But since there is nothing for the particle to interact with,it shouldn't lose its quantum coherence!How is this paradox resolved?

Comment: We do not have a definite theory of quantum gravity yet.

Comment: I think going to a relativistic limit is unnecessary. In Newtonian gravity, you will have a gravitational potential $\Phi$, so the particle will always interact with the background field. Will that break coherence? Nope

Comment: Not all interactions are measurements or cause decoherence. A particle in a simple harmonic oscillator potential is also interacting with an external force field, namely the linear force field corresponding to the parabolic potential. Does it cause loss of coherence? Similarly, a charged particle moving in a background electric/magnetic field is also a well-studied and relatively simple example where you get usual unitary evolution for the test particle. [...]

Comment: [...] So, what do you think is different about the gravitational potential? In fact, for a quantum particle in static background gravitational field, the math would work out the same as for a quantum (charged) particle in a static background electric field except that you replace $q$ with $m$. Of course, all of this would change for strong gravitational fields or when you consider the back-reaction of the particle on the background gravitational field, and we don't know how to treat these things because we don't have a final theory of quantum gravity.

Comment: @DvijD.C. but the path it will travel in the  presence of the gravitational field will be 1 , it cannot move in multiple geodesics can it?

Comment: Hi @CartoonRyan, does a classical charged particle have multiple trajectories under an electric field? Of course, not! However, the trajectory of a quantum charged particle under an electric field would be described by a superposition of multiple classical trajectories (in the Feynman path integral sense). The same thing would happen for a quantum particle under a gravitational field -- again, I am completely ignoring the backreaction and the field is assumed to be weak. Btw, welcome to Physics StackExchange! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Consider a particle which moving inside a gravitational field.Will it lose its quantum coherence?

In quantum physics, where the term "quantum coherence" can have a physics meaning, a single particle moving in an empty universe will not lose any coherence with itself, as it is the only thing in this universe.

A single particle moving in a gravitational field in quantum physics, needs a quantum mechanical solution for the state "particle in gravitational field", and , assuming gravity is quantized, it will not lose its coherence because one wavefunction will define its state.

> According to GR , the particle will follow a geodesic but if it does then shouldn't its wavefunction have been collapsed?

GR is a classical theory, even if one describes the particle with a quantum mechanical wavefunction, suppose it is a [hydrogen atom,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydwf.html), classical GR cannot interact with the wavefunction and induce a collapse, i.e. a different wavefunction to the system "gravity+hydrogen atom". If we assume the gravitational potential and solve for quantum mechanical bound states, again, one wavefunction will describe the particle and there is no way it can "collapse" . Actually quantum mechanical [bound states of the neutron](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27308133/) in the gravitational field of the earth have been measured experimentally.

> But since there is nothing for the particle to interact with,it shouldn't lose its quantum coherence!How is this paradox resolved?

There is no paradox, you are just misinterpreting  classical and  quantum states.